# Split URL into array and then change url depending on language

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to change the url depending on if the site is loaded on a different language. I think I'm close.

The is the check if the site is just .com (if that's the case leave it alone) OR .com/fr/slug .com/de/slug .com/es/slug turns into .com/fr .com/de ...

The english site. One that's just .com/slug is .com//slug. Looking to fix that

```
   // take url and put into array
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    var newPathname = "";
    for (i = 0; i < pathArray.length; i++) {
      // if statement to prevent extra '/' at end of url
      if (i < 2 ){
        newPathname += pathArray[i] + "/";
      }
    }
    newPathname.toString();

    if (newPathname == "/de/" || "/fr/" || "/es/" || "/ja/" || "/zh-hant/"){
      var newURL = window.location.host + newPathname;
    console.log(newURL);
    document.querySelector(".navbar__logo__wrapper").href = newURL;
    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the element of .navbar__logo__img ?

Comment: O god I was selecting the wrong element. It's actually .navbar__logo__wrapper. Still not 100% working tho

Comment: It's an <a> tag

Comment: What is not 100% working ? If it's <a> tag than it should assign href properly.

Comment: Surely your server can do this for you, why do this client-side?

Comment: The english site. One that's just .com/slug is .com//slug

Comment: `newPathname == "/de/" || "/fr/" || "/es/" || "/ja/" || "/zh-hant/"` isn't valid, it should be something like `if (newPathname == "/de/" || newPathname === "/fr/") { ... }` etc...